# Setting property value within an If statement

Tags: objective-c, xcode, if-statement, sprite-kit

How would I set a value for a property within an if statement that can be accessed outside of the scope of the if statement?
My attempt:

```
@interface GamePlayScene ()
@property (nonatomic) PlayerNode *player;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint playerPosition;
@end

@implementation GamePlayScene
- (void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view{
     ...
    if (IS_IPHONE_4){
        self.playerPosition = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-210, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-100);

    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_5){
        self.playerPosition = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-230, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-100);

    }
    self.player = [PlayerNode playerAtPosition:_playerPosition withImage:@"HeroRun1"];
    [self addChild:self.player];
    ...
}
```

The `playerPosition` property does not retain the value set within the `if statement`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you define `IS_IPHONE_4` and `IS_IPHONE_5` in your code? Use `NSLog` to check whether the program does run into the if-statement. Also add an `else` statement to set the default case for `self.playerPosition`.

Comment: theyre defined in another file as follows:`#define IS_IPHONE_4 (fabs((double)[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height - (double)480) < DBL_EPSILON)`

Comment: Ahh, it hasnt been going through the if statement.

Comment: @Exprosul Does you app support portrait, landscape or both?

Comment: It only supports landscape